# DB connector from GraphQL to Teradata

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, teradata, apollo-server, prisma-graphql

Please let me know your suggestions for connecting GraphQL API to Teradata tables.

Looks like Prisma doesn't cover Teradata. Also, i don't see recommendations for GraphQL to Teradata in Google.

Regards,
Phani Kiran

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of googling, come to know that, there are no ORMs available right now from GraphQL to Teradata. But, we can use [node-teradata npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-teradata) to connect to Teradata and fetch data from GraphQL.